# Emulate BTreeMap::pop_last in stable Rust 1.65 or older

Tags: rust

Editor's note: as of [Rust 1.66.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/12/15/Rust-1.66.0.html#stabilized-apis), `BTreeMap::pop_last` has been stabilized.

---

In stable Rust 1.65 or older, is there a way to write a function equivalent to [BTreeMap::pop_last](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.pop_last)?

The best I could come up with is:

```rust
fn map_pop_last<K, V>(m: &mut BTreeMap<K, V>) -> Option<(K, V)>
where
    K: Ord + Clone,
{
    let last = m.iter().next_back();
    if let Some((k, _)) = last {
        let k_copy = k.clone();
        return m.remove_entry(&k_copy);
    }
    None
}
```

It works, but it requires that the key is cloneable. BTreeMap::pop_last from Rust nightly imposes no such constraint.

If I remove the cloning like this

```rust
fn map_pop_last<K, V>(m: &mut BTreeMap<K, V>) -> Option<(K, V)>
where
    K: Ord,
{
    let last = m.iter().next_back();
    if let Some((k, _)) = last {
        return m.remove_entry(k);
    }
    None
}
```

it leads to

```rust
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*m` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> ...
   |
.. |     let last = m.iter().next_back();
   |                -------- immutable borrow occurs here
.. |     if let Some((k, _)) = last {
.. |         return m.remove_entry(k);
   |                ^^------------^^^
   |                | |
   |                | immutable borrow later used by call
   |                mutable borrow occurs here
```

Is there a way to work around this issue without imposing additional constraints on map key and value types?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to implement this in safe Rust. You could perhaps copy chunks of the source code from std, to get the same implementation.

Comment: @PeterHall Unfortunately the [source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/collections/btree/map.rs.html#726-728) uses `alloc::collections::btree::borrow::DormantMutRef` which is not accessible through the public API. You would need to either re-implement it or find another way.

Comment: And as more general point, copying parts of unstable source code is not safer than compiling on nightly, probably less.

Comment: @Anonyme2000 copying _**specific**_ parts of unstable source is definitely safer than just using nightly.

Comment: @Anonyme2000 Yes, you would need to copy all of the internal types that it uses, not just the function body.

Comment: Looking at the source of `pop_last`, it relies only on `last_entry` which is itself safe and AFAICT relies on no additional nightly APIs. So, assuming all the types used are public (big assumption) the bodies of `last_entry` and `pop_last` together should get you a safe solution to this problem.

Comment: @BallpointBen `last_entry` uses the private `DormantMutRef` type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a way to work around this issue without imposing additional constraints on map key and value types?

It doesn't appear doable in *safe* Rust, at least not with reasonable algorithmic complexity. (See Aiden4's answer for a solution that does it by re-building the whole map.)

But if you're allowed to use unsafe, and if you're determined enough that you want to delve into it, this code could do it:

```
// Safety: if key uses shared interior mutability, the comparison function
// must not use it. (E.g. it is not allowed to call borrow_mut() on a
// Rc<RefCell<X>> inside the key). It is extremely unlikely that such a
// key exists, but it's possible to write it, so this must be marked unsafe.
unsafe fn map_pop_last<K, V>(m: &mut BTreeMap<K, V>) -> Option<(K, V)>
where
    K: Ord,
{
    // We make a shallow copy of the key in the map, and pass a
    // reference to the copy to BTreeMap::remove_entry(). Since
    // remove_entry() is not dropping the key/value pair (it's returning
    // it), our shallow copy will remain throughout the lifetime of
    // remove_entry(), even if the key contains references.
    let (last_key_ref, _) = m.iter().next_back()?;
    let last_key_copy = ManuallyDrop::new(std::ptr::read(last_key_ref));
    m.remove_entry(&last_key_copy)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9fe0170dcc86b051e91d9444a4e4a928)

Comment: Note that even though `remove_entry` is not dropping the key it may move it internally prior to returning it, which would invalidate the reference before it returns (although it likely won't try to use the reference again by that point explaining why MIRI doesn't complain).

Comment: @Jmb No. It won't invalidate the reference because the reference points to a local copy of the key. The validity my comment refers to is in case the key internally contains further references, which would be invalidated by it getting dropped. (But won't, because it's getting moved to the caller.)

Comment: Oh, right. So it should be safe unless the key is of some exotic type that does something funny (and unsafe) in its comparison function.

Comment: @Jmb Preceisely. I tried to come up with a way how that would fail, e.g. if the key contains interior mutability and the comparison function mutates it - but I failed to think of something that would cause UB. If someone does, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Here's a contrived example that panics: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c3b06ee429d35d6afbf6772337ff52aa). If we replaced the `RefCell` with a custom implementation that doesn't check for duplicate mutable borrows, we would get UB.

Comment: @Jmb Though, such an implementation would be in violation of Rust's aliasing rules anyway. E.g. simply comparing such an object to itself would create mutable aliasing.

Comment: @Jmb I think I've now come up with an example where safe code results in unsoundness (when calling my function): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c90516f22d2f455ef3d18b21bff3225e The trick is to replace `Box<RefCell<i32>>` with `RefCell<Box<i32>>`. Then `borrow_mut()` on `self.r` and `other.r` are decoupled and **don't panic**, and their `.as_mut()` give out two mutable refs to the same `i32`, which is UB.

Comment: And with a slight modification we can get miri to complain: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c90516f22d2f455ef3d18b21bff3225e

Comment: @Jmb I've now updated the answer to mark the function as unsafe. I can't think of a way to provide a safe abstraction that works for all key types and doesn't depend on implementation details of `BTreeMap::remove_entry()`.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to work around this issue without imposing additional constraints on  map key and value types?

You can't do it efficiently in safe rust, but it is possible:

```rust
fn map_pop_last<K, V>(m: &mut BTreeMap<K, V>) -> Option<(K, V)>
where
    K: Ord,
{
    let mut temp = BTreeMap::new();
    std::mem::swap(m, &mut temp);
    let mut iter = temp.into_iter();
    let ret = iter.next_back();
    m.extend(iter);
    ret  
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ff0aa971fcef8737dcc5fc72504b109b)

This will do a full traversal of the map but is safe.

Answer (score 2):

We can even be sure that it is not possible to mutate the map in-place with the current offer of interfaces in safe Rust (version 1.59, at the time of writing):

To extract the key, we need to look the keys of the map. "Look at" implies borrowing here. This gives us a `&K` reference that also borrows the entire map.

Now, a problem arises: To call any of these `remove*` methods, we need to mutably borrow the map again, which we cannot do since we still hold the reference to the key that we are about to extract - these lifetimes overlap and it won't compile.

Another approach could be to try to get hold of the `Entry`, but to get one through the `.entry` method, we need have an owned `K` too.